# How to do fire-and-forget client server calls in ZeroMQ?

Tags: zeromq

I want to make a call to a server without needing to wait for reply. The reply simply doesn't matter in my case. So it's a kind of a fire-and-forget type of calls. The docs doesn't seem to have a simple, straight forward answer. One place it has complicated topology for "full asynchronous" **`REQ-REP`** and other place it hints that **`DEALER-ROUTER`** pattern might some how be useful. I think this is simple enough thing that ZeroMQ should be able to do right out of box without having to open too many ports, create more than 2 layers in topology and introducing any extra latency. One other place I read about timeouts and thought about just setting to 0, but I have no idea what happens to messages arriving after timeout. Another example code [**here**](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:asyncsrv)

```
//  Asynchronous client-to-server (DEALER to ROUTER)
    ...
//  This is our client task
//  It connects to the server, and then sends a request once per second
//  It collects responses as they arrive, and it prints them out. We will
//  run several client tasks in parallel, each with a different random ID.
    ...
```

comes close, but still looks like a client must keep polling for response or the queue will grow out of bound. I just want to do simple pure and fast fire and forget call.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: If you don't care about the response, why not a traditional **pub sub** ?`zmq.socket('pub') / zmq.socket('sub');` then you send the message to a specific  topic

Comment: pub-sub is  more complex to simulate fire and forget RPC call and would have more latency.

Comment: Two answers so far covered it, docs mention it, it's the `push - pull` combination. It's exactly what you asked for, fire and forget. You want to make a call - you `push` to the server and server `pull`s. No reply needed from the server. If you do need a reply *eventually*, you implement the same logic for the client, only this time client pulls and server pushes, and you achieve what the docs state about this pattern  - a *pipeline*.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this. 
One side create message channel (using bind operation). It's *Receiver*.

Another side send messages in to the channel. It's *Sender*.

We have 2 options:

1. *Receiver* is accumulating new messages "inside" and is processing these;
2. *Sender* is available. *Receiver* is not. *Sender* is accumulating messages "inside". When *Receiver* will be started then ZeroMq will send all messages on *Receiver* side. Now *Receiver* is accumulating old and new messages "inside" and is processing these.

Sender:

```
void* senderSocket = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUSH);
zmq_connect(senderSocket, "...");
...
zmq_msg_send(&zmqMessage, senderSocket, 0);
```

Receiver:

```
void* pullSocket = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PULL);
zmq_bind(pullSocket, "...");
...
zmq_msg_recv(&message, pullSocket, 0);
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add a short note on why and how this work.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the **simplest way** to achieve ***this***?

---

### Scaling?
Scaling rulez!

---

**For low numbers of clients
and low density of TPS:**
 - may use ( client-side ) **`PUSH`**-archetype + **`PULL`**-archetype ( server-side ) + check for round-robin service logic + proper HWM settings for the RX-buffer

or
- may use ( exclusive ) **`PAIR-PAIR`** Formal Communication Pattern, where each client may use it's soloist connection, being centrally polled in a non-blocking mode on the server side for a fast recv() detection.

**For higher counts
or unmanaged client populations:**
- may enjoy the uni-directional Formal Communication Pattern with a **`PUB`**-archetype on client-side + **`SUB`**-archetype on servers-side, being non-restrictively subscribed to all subjects in such central `topic`-filter.